# How do I show and hide add to cart button with php?

Tags: php, magento

Im altering my addtocart.phtml on my magento website and what im trying to do is have a little bit of PHP code that simplies hides and shows the add to cart button if a product is in a certain category. My thoughts on the code would be :

```
<?php if($_product_category == "beds"){
    <div class="add-to-cart">
    <div class="qty">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="add-cart">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "> </i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
</div>
} else {
      //hide add to cart button
}
?>
```

and then i would simply place that in the addtocart.phtml and then it would show and display the button where I need it

Comment: i think you are doing it your code will show the addtocart button if the category is "beds" else it will not do anything thus it will not show it is that what are you looking for ?

Comment: You should ask a question up there. Right now you are only describing what you have done so far – but not if there was some problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i feel first of all you should get all  categories of a product and than after place a check that if a specified category exist in that categories than show the button and in else case hide the button you can get the categories by below code

```
<?php
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
        echo $_cat->getName();
    } 
    if(in_array($cats,'your_category_id')){ ?>
        <div class="add-to-cart">
        <div class="qty">
            <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php endif; ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="add-cart">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "> </i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php  } else {
          //hide add to cart button
    }

    ?>
```

i have use a category id because in future we can also change the name of id so in that case there will be no need of change in file

Comment: kinda working removes the add to cart button and replaces it with i think the name of the product, but does it for every product not just category id 11 [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/2501s07.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you use an attribute and some php code to activate and de activate the buy it now button [Example Post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/how-to-disable-add-to-cart-on-specific-products-and-instead-display-view-det)